# Using Salt's LocalClient, how to achieve same results or specify '-v' arg in test.ping command?

Tags: python, salt-stack

Using the CLI, I can enter the following:

> salt '*' test.ping -v

The resulting output is as follows:

> minion_A:
>       True
>   minion_B:
>       True
>   minion_C:
>       True
>   minion_D:
>       Minion did not return

How do I get the same results using the `LocalClient`?
This is what I'm currently attempting and only returns the minions with a response of `True`:

```
self.localClient.cmd('*', 'test.ping', ['-v'])
```

**Update**:
Based on an indication that there could be a *bug* with `arg` tuples in the command, I have also tried the following:

```
args = ('-v',)
return self.localClient.cmd('*', 'test.ping', arg=args)
```

...sadly, still not successful

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you checked if the command is outputting to logs instead of returning via the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could do was to execute from the `localClient` a `test.ping`.

If the response is `{}` I assume a False return from salt-master.
Otherwise, a True is received.

Answer (score 6):

`test.ping` function doesn't take any arguments, the `-v` is passed to the `salt` command.   See: [ping](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.test.html#salt.modules.test.ping)

The following two commands are identical:

```
# salt '*' test.ping -v
Executing job with jid 20140825123756314894
-------------------------------------------

palabras:
    True

# salt '*' -v test.ping
Executing job with jid 20140825124044472307
-------------------------------------------

palabras:
    True
```

To get the raw version of the original output, use the following code. (You can call SaltCMD directly to get the full, formatted output, but it'll use its own `LocalClient`.)

## source

```
from pprint import pprint
import salt.client
local = salt.client.LocalClient()
pprint( local.cmd_full_return(
    '*', 'test.ping', verbose=True,
    ) )
```

## output

```
Executing job with jid 20140825131629740741
-------------------------------------------

{'palabras': {'ret': True, 'success': True}}
```

Comment: Will check this shortly.

Comment: I added `verbose=True` but still do not receive anything for minions that cannot be **pinged**...actually, I get a list of all the minions, but without acknowledging which are actually returning True to the ping. ...hmmm ...

Comment: So this doesn't really answer my question: How can I get the same results of `'*' test.ping -v` using `localClient.cmd('*', 'test.ping')`? If you have a minion that is not up and execute the CLI command, you get a return that the minion did not respond.

Comment: This does not answer the question as I intended. It explains *why* my attempts failed but does not provide a working answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unmentioned in the documentation is an argument `show_timeout` which can be set to `True` to include results from minions which timed out, and also doesn't print debug info every time. Tested with `salt 2015.8.4 (Beryllium)` but it looks like this [still defaults](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/client/__init__.py#L1271) to `False` at the time of this writing.

### code

```
import salt.client
from pprint import pprint
local = salt.client.LocalClient()

# Use show_timeout=True to make salt return
# results for disconnected minions
pings = local.cmd('*', 'test.ping', show_timeout=True)
pprint(pings)
```

### output

```
{'host_one': True,
 'host_two': 'Minion did not return. [Not connected]',
 'host_three': True}
```